# Совет по решению задачи (автоматическая отправка по e-mail)

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

Нужен ваш совет по решению задачи. Задача такая: автоматическое формирование счетов с печатью (формат pdf) и отправка на электронную почту. Образец счета такой (прикрепляю его)
Какие средства имеются:

1. MS SQL Server 2017;
2. Delphi 5.
3. Мое желание выполнить эту задачу

Пока сделал следующим образом. Пользователь формируем отчет с помощью Quick Report (3.5.0) с печатью. Далее отправляет его на виртуальный pdf-принтер (Microsoft Print to PDF) и получает pdf-файл. Далее, этот файл отправляет по почте.

Что еще.... Счета формируются на основании накладной. Таблица клиентов и их e-mail адреса хранятся в базе данных.

Нужен ваш совет. Как можно автоматизировать данную задачу имеющимися средствами? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Delphi поновее, FastReport (умеет генерить отчеты сразу в PDF), Indy (или другой SMTP клиент)

Comment: Delphi, конечно, согласен, что нужно обновлять. Но слишком проблематично. Возможно будут проблемы при компиляции имеющихся исходников (много нестандартных компонентов, плюс вся система отчетности построена на Quick Report). В общем, геморно (пробовал раньше на тестовом ПК. При компиляции возникли проблемы).

Comment: Если совсем костыльно, то делай (генерируй) html страницу и печатай её в pdf. Так же можно делать PostScript файл и его конвертировать консольной программой в pdf (может чуть легче).

Comment: средствами reporting services то не решить никак? смущает, наличие печати и пподписей, хз может ли он их вставиьт. а в целом отправка пдф отчета реализуется без участия делфей. Правда, пдф он так себе генерит, но мб в 17й версии получше.

Comment: Может и можно. Я, если честно, не знаю. Сейчас как раз поднимаю его (reporting services) на тестовом ПК.  Дело в том, что я раньше никогда с ним не работал. И в конторе он не поднят. Так что мне выпадает такая "честь" - поднять reporting services. Пока могу сказать. Под Server выделено 16 гб. памяти.  Сам процесс SQL Server занимает (если смотреть по диспетчеру задач) 11.8 гб. Поэтому, возможно я могу быть и не прав, то тогда под потребление памяти Reporting Services нужно ограничить до 1 гб. Всего на серваке 24 гб. памяти.